# open one box, close all that are open

Tags: jquery

i have the following (which obviously i cant do!)

```
function dropBox() {
    $("#reportWrapper a").bind("click", function(){
        $("#reportWrapper a").each(function(i){
            $(this).animate({
                        height: '20px'
            }, 1000);                               
        });
        $(this).parents("div:eq(0)").animate({
            height: '100px'
        }, 1000);
    });
}
```

What i want is to open one that is clicked on and close all ones that are open. The box opens box the others dont close. Any help much appreciated.
Regards

Comment: Can you put part of the HTML code to help you?

Answer (score 0):

If you close them in a way that changes the `display` property to `none`, then you can use the jQuery `:visible` selector to select all others that are open.

Comment: Im sorry im new to jQuery (PHP man) could you elaberate some more?

Comment: can yoiu select an element by is css property? i.e. element.css.height.200px ?

Answer (score 0):

Can enyone see why thisa wouldn't work?

```
function dropBox() {
    $("#reportWrapper a").bind("click", function(){
        var clicked = $(this);
        $("#reportWrapper a").each(function(){  
            if( clicked.attr("name") != $(this).attr("name") )
            {
                $(this).animate({
                    height: '20px'
                }, 1000);
            }
            else
            {
                clicked.parents("div:eq(0)").animate({
                    height: '100px'
                }, 1000);
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Yet again, the box clicked opens, but the one that is open does not close

```
function dropBox() {
    $("#reportWrapper a").bind("click", function(){
        var clicked = $(this);
        $("#reportWrapper a").each(function(){  
            if( clicked.attr("name") !== $(this).attr("name") )
            {
                alert("this: " + $(this).attr("name") + "clicked: " + clicked.attr("name"));
                $(this).animate({
                    height: '20px'
                }, 1000);
            }
            else
            {
                clicked.parents("div:eq(0)").animate({
                    height: '100px'
                }, 1000);
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Above, alerts everyone apart from the one thats clicked so im stumped

God damn... just sussed it

Answer (score 0):

```
function dropBox() {
    $("#reportWrapper a").bind("click", function(){
            var clicked = $(this);
            $("#reportWrapper a").each(function(){  
                    if( clicked.attr("name") !== $(this).attr("name") )
                    {
                            $(this).parents("div:eq(0)").animate({
                                    height: '20px'
                            }, 1000);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                            clicked.parents("div:eq(0)").animate({
                                    height: '100px'
                            }, 1000);
                    }
            });
    });
```

}

WORKS!